# Node.js passport - keep login alive even changing to a different url

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have a working page secured with passport. It works fine. Opening the page the user credentials for login are asked and the navigation bar is adjusted for the user level. The user can navigate through the protected area and do stuff.

I am looking for a way to keep the login alive, even if the user changes to a another website and comes back to my page. There should be no new login necessary. The session should only be canceled, pressing the logout button or after a specific time period. I think that could be done with a secure cookie. How do I manage that?

```
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));
    passport.deserializeUser(async function(id, done){

        // local strategy
        // ... checking user and do something

    });
   
    passport.use(
      new LocalStrategy(async function(username, password, done){
        let user;
  
        // local strategy
        // ... checking user and do something

      }),
    );
  
    app.use(
      expressSession({
        secret: 'top secret',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
      }),
    );
  
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session(
      { 
          secret: 'my secret',
          cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
      }
    ));
  
    app.post(
      '/login',
      passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login.html' }), async function (request, response){

        // redirect to a specific route
        
      },
    );
  
    app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
      req.logout();
      res.redirect('/login.html');
```

Comment: Method 1) When login, issue a secure cookie (httpOnly), then on each page, send a request to your server to verify the cookie exist (because javascript cannot access the secure cookie). If it exist, then user is logged in. Method 2) Read up on JWT

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I get it right. I have to create a secure cookie on the clientside and forward it with the login request to the server, where it will be stored. When I go back to the page, first the stored cookie will be checked, if available no login required. How do I forward a secure cookie with express? First time I work with cookies.

Comment: Actually, you already have `.passport.session`, you can set `secure` true, and on each page, send a post request to check the session is correct. For verifying session is authenticate, you can probably check for req.user in passport. If req.user exist, return status(200), else return error. On client side, if 200 is received, user is authenticated.